# Updating Kafka event and synchronizing in database

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I'm new to event-driven architecture and have a specific and basic doubt, which is probably clear for some. I'm implementing a Kafka topic that will have a connector to synchronize information with Azure Cosmos DB (Core, Containers).

There will be a microservice that will perform different operations. Among them, it will be able to send a message with a complex object to the topic and synchronize it with the database. The doubt I have is about another endpoint that should only update certain fields of that object that was sent to the topic and also update it in the database.

I understand that it is not possible to update an event that was sent to the topic, but rather a new message must be sent. How true is this? How would I then update what is in the database without inserting a new record?

```
{ "name": "josh", "others": "...", "status": "E" }
```

For example, assuming that there is already an event on the topic and it is also already synchronized in the database:

How would you change only the "status" field to "M" without creating a new record in the database, but instead updating the existing one?

result:

```
{ "name": "josh", "others": "...", "status": "M" }
```

I know that to send a message it is done in this way, but I don't know how I would update it and synchronize it in the database.

```
public ResponseEntity<?> sendMessage(@RequestBody MyComplexObject obj) {
    kafkaTemplate.send("my-topic", obj);
    return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
}
```

Comment: have you checked cosmosdb connector in kafka-connect?, if yes and it doesn't support it, or you can't use it, then you will do it manually, by creating a consumer to consume the messages you pushed and do the logic to update or insert into cosmosdb

Regarding updating an event in kafka, this is not doable, however you can keep the most recent message for a specific key using log compaction -yet it is not deterministic- check this for more details docs.quix.io/sdk-intro.html#streaming-contexts

Answer (score 1):

> not possible to update an event that was sent to the topic, but rather a new message must be sent. How true is this?

Somewhat true. Yes, you need a new event, but a compacted Kafka topic can be used to override old events with a matching record-key.

> How would I then update what is in the database without inserting a new record?

Similar to above, you'll need some lookup key as well for the database, such as `name`, or generate some UUID per `MyComplexObject`.